# How to use steps from multiple plugins but with same name?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins has two plugins to generate cucumber report, but with same name: 'cucumber'

My Jenkins has the following two plugins to generate cucumber report:

## 1: https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-testresult-plugin/

## 2: https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin

But both of them use same step name 'cucumber' in pipeline.
For example for #2:

```
                    cucumber buildStatus: 'UNSTABLE',
                            fileIncludePattern: '**/*cucumber-report.json',
                            trendsLimit: 10
```

For example for #1:

```
                    cucumber '**/*cucumber-report.json'
```

My question is  how can I specify which one I want to use? is there anything like class name can be leveraged? if yes, how to find out the class name?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to do the same as you did in your example #2.

```
cucumber buildStatus: ...
```

In your example you call the [Cucumber reports plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/cucumber-reports/).

If you want to use the plugin for [cucumber json test reporting](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/cucumber-testresult-plugin/) you can simply follow your pattern from your example #2 and call the plugin by specifing the function `testResults`.

```
cucumber testResults: ...
```

Quote:

> To use this feature, first set up your build to run tests, then
>   specify the path to Cucumber JSON files in the Ant glob syntax, such
>   as **/build/test-reports/*.json.

Comment: Thanks mkemmerz! But you reponse does not work, I got the following error:Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 71: Invalid parameter "testResults", did you mean "trendsLimit"? @ line 71, column 30.
                       cucumber testResults: '**/*cucumber-report.json'
                                ^

1 error

Comment: Do you have both plugins installed on your Jenkins?